# How did this site prevent me from creating multiple accounts?

Tags: vpn, tor, drm

Disclaimer: I just realized this question may read a little bit as if I'm trying to promote this site. I'm not. Now that I think about it, I'm unsure whether this site even has a proper license from content owners. I'm not in any way affiliated with the site in question.

I just bought a music album from http://www.soundike.com/.

When I created an account, I noticed that they said I would get two free songs simply by confirming my e-mail address. It was true, I clicked a link sent to my Gmail account, and I was then able to download two songs even before paying anything.

Out of curiosity, I then attempted to create a second account using my iCloud e-mail address. The only data the site asks for is my e-mail address and a password. I changed my passwords each time.

I did not receive any confirmation e-mail. (I also checked my spam folder.)

I figured they must be using cookies or my IP or something to prevent multiple accounts. So I activated a VPN and opened an Incognito window in Chrome. I then registered again, this time with an Outlook.com address. No registration e-mail came.

Puzzled by this, I launched Tor and tried to register again with a new Gmail address. No confirmation e-mail, even when accessing the site through Tor.

How could they achieve this? Could they be blocking connections that come from a VPN or Tor?

Comment: I am not sure it wil help but maybe you can give this a read? [how do sites track you](http://www.howtogeek.com/115483/htg-explains-learn-how-websites-are-tracking-you-online/)

Comment: Many of my site registration mails on rediff used to go to spam by default. Why not check your spam folder?

Comment: @Limit Yup, checked my spam folder in all cases, nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not based on IP address and I was able to create two accounts:

1. Create an account using your gmail account
2. Go to incognito mode and create an account using 10 minute mail. (There was a 10 minute delay between the two steps)

Mind you, you are gaming the system. It is ethically wrong.

Comment: Interesting. I tried this, too. It worked the first time. I then noticed that I stay logged into the site even though I open a new incognito window. Surely that must be IP based? I mean Chrome isn't supposed to keep anything between sessions. The third time I didn't receive any email to my new 10 minute mail address.

Comment: What if you log out and then try this again?

Comment: Yeah, tried it again now in a brand new incognito window. Logged out, used a new 10 minute mail address, no e-mail came. Even with Tor it doesn't work. Maybe all the Tor exit nodes have already been used for this, so they won't work.

Comment: I got one just now:  no-reply@soundike.com Registration Confirmation Dear Customer, Thank you for registering with S May 17, 2016 5:03:23 AM

Comment: OK, so you have done it like 3 times in a row? All on the same IP?

Comment: Yes. This is the third time. I did it. But there was a looot of time between second and third time.

Comment: OK. There was a lot of time between my first and second time too. Weird. Can you try a fourth time immediately just for the experiment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39881/discussion-between-limit-and-fiksdal).

Comment: @Fiksdal  Did it. no-reply@soundike.com Registration Confirmation Dear Customer, Thank you for registering with S May 17, 2016 5:09:20 AM
I verified that the third and the 4th time had same IP and am sure that the previous ones did too